# How can we update custom field using SFDX CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-field, salesforcedx-cli, customsetting, field-update

I have a custom field under custom settings. The settings type is "Hierarchy" and custom field type being "Text".

I two jenkins pipeline which I am using for Integration and Deployment respectively along with SFDX CLI.

Using SFDX CLI, I am able to retrieve the value of custom field using below command,

```
rc = command "sfdx force:data:soql:query --query \"SELECT git_commit_id__c FROM latest_git_commit__c LIMIT 1\" -u ${USERNAME} --json > output.json"
```

However, once deployment is successful I need to update this field in the Salesforce Org. Is there a way we can update custom field using SFDX CLI ?

I tried with the below option but that did not worked out.

```
 sfdx force:data:record:update -t -s CustomObject__c -w "git_commit_id__c=b7e99877528aefc2d60493e66df38530102c4d43" -v "git_commit_id__c=abcd" -u ${username}
```

»   Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.157.0 to 7.166.1.
ERROR running force:data:record:update:
SELECT id FROM CustomObject__c WHERE git_commit_id__c
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:16
sObject type 'CustomObject__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using anonymous apex scripting?

Comment: No, I am actually new to Salesforce and not aware about apex code or scripting. But any pointers to it may help.

Comment: Here's a [forum post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yXFIAY) with at least one answer showing the sort of code you can use. For anonymous apex via sfdx see [force:apex:execute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm).